# Subdivide edges/polygons in 3dS Max?

Tags: 3d, 3ds-max, modeling

What is the way to subdivide individual edges/polygons in 3dS Max? That is, to add more vertexes on edges and to add more vertices/edges on faces.

- For edges - [image]
- For a polygons - [image]

Anybody knows how to do that or something similar to that in 3dS Max?

Note - The images are in vertex mode. The mode doesn't matter, but I'm more interested in how to do it in polygon mode.

Comment: For the first part, have you tried the `Insert Vertex` command?

Comment: Thanks. No haven't. is it in the command panel? (I'll look on it now)

Comment: I've found the "insert vertex", but when I click on the button I'm lost. It's like nothing happens. What is the approach for a polygon?

Comment: I don't use 3D Max but a google search turned up to select the `Edge` then hit `Insert Vertex` which it mentions is in a Modifier panel of some sort.

Answer (score 4):

For edges:

1. Open grid and snap settings, click midpoint
2. Select your object, in modify panel click edit poly
3. In "selection" rollout click edge
4. Find and click "insert vertex button", target needed edge and click it

That`s it!

Comment: Hey ngspawn, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 2):

Select the object you wish to apply the subdivide to. Go to the modify panel and in the modifier list go to object space modifiers. Select Subdivide from the list. It should now be applied to the selected object

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the confusion. I meant about individual edges/faces, not the hole model. I'll update the question.

Comment: No problem, the same method can be used, you just need to split the face off into an individual object first, before applying the subdiv.

Comment: Thanks. That can be useful at times, but isn't there a faster way, without splitting it? When using Blender, for the edges you just select the edge and hit "W" and from the manu "subdivide" and for polygons is the same method. Is there something similar to that or whatever the approach, the operation to be done with no splitting (one object)?

Comment: Aren't there any tools to do specifically that or what can i use?

Answer (score 2):

Found this post via Google, and thought I'd provide an expanded list of options for achieving this result from another article on the topic. Depending on your use case, here are a different approach that will add a vertex or, in some cases, add multiple. Admittedly, some are better suited than others. All use the Editable Poly modifier's tool set.

**1. Insert Vertex Tool**

In edge mode, there's a button labeled `Insert Vertex`. It does just what it says. Just click on an edge to add as many vertices as you want. Enable snaps (midpoint ideally) to avoid going crazy.

**2. Connect Tool**
Click any two edges while in edge mode and you can use the `Connect` tool. This creates an extra edge between the two (or more) selected edges. There's a new vertex at each endpoint.

**3. Quick Slice**
Quick slice will create an edge on a two-dimensional plane (or 3D plane if in a non-projected view) that creates a new vertex point at each intersecting point with another edge on your model. Not an approach I'd use but would certainly create extra vertices.

**4. Slice Plane**
Similar to the quick slice tool but lets you use the gizmo tool to adjust in 3D space from a 2D view. Creates many vertices at intersection points.

**5. Tesselate Tool**
Again, not an approach I'd recommend but can be useful in some cases. Essential subdivides your geometry by adding extra edges. Will be restricted to whatever sub-object selection is made (face or edges). New vertices are at the endpoints.

**Source** (has pictures): https://www.rendernode.com/ways-to-add-vertices-in-3ds-max/

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to approach this, one free and one paid.

Both expand the underdeveloped tools in 3DS Max considerably.

Free: Soulburn Scripts : [Edge Divider](http://www.neilblevins.com/cg_tools/soulburnscripts/soulburnscripts.htm)

Paid: Rappatools 3 : [Insert Verts](http://remusjuncu.com/rappatools/)

I've made a [screencast of both methods](http://www.screencast.com/t/zMQ81nEsXB), hope it helps.

Comment: You can add the immages (jpg, png) here by editing your answer and adding the images. One user with more rep (for example I) can add the ! to activate the images. BTW: Welcome to GD.SE!

Answer (score 1):

1. turn object into editable poly and go to edge mod
2. select the opposed edges and "connect" then in many segments as you whant the number of vertex
3. select the polygnons resulting from this opperation and "remove" then

The faces was removed but the vertex remains there so...

4. in the edge opposed, select the extra vertex and "remove"
   it's ease

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert to editable poly if it isn't already.
2. Edge select mode.
3. Select opposing edges.
4. Use "Connect" settings to create a subdivision in the quad you have crossed.  You can do one or many subs.
5. Then do the other two opposing edges.

Also, the Polygon Modeling menu (formerly "Graphite tools" has some options.  Swift Loop is super helpful and effective.